# Can child Parameter sets inherit from another object?

Tags: origen-sdk

In the Origen::Parameters [docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/#Defining_Child_Sets) I see that parameter sets can inherit from other parameter sets within the same scope.  I also [see](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/#Tracking_the_Context_of_Another_Object) that parameter contexts can be set to follow another object.  What I am looking for seems to be a combination of the two features:

```
# In top level DUT :top
define_params :default do |p|
  p.hello = 'world'
end

# In child sub-block :child
define_params :default, inherit: 'top.default' do |p|
  p.child_param = 'goodbye'
end

# In debugger
dut.child.params.keys # => [:hello, :child_param]
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible today, seems like if would be a good feature to add though.

Answer (score 1):

Origen now supports [parameter set remote inheritance](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/#Defining_Child_Sets).  Here is an example:

```
define_params :ate, inherit: 'dut.ddr.default' do |params|
  params.erase.time = 40.mS
end
```